# Google Analytics with a fixed URL site

Tags: google-analytics

I have a issue to track the user navigation in a site with **FIXED URLs**

No matter where the user is the URL will always be http://www.myurl.com

And so in my report the user stay always be at the on http://www.myurl.com

I would like to know if i can add something to the tracking script to improve the user tracking data

```
<!-- default google tacking code -->
<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', $cod, 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

**UPDATE**

My solution:

Main page

```
    <!-- default google tacking code -->

    $this->response->insertScript($this->_minify("

                (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                ga('create', '" . $cod . "', 'auto');
                ga('set', 'page', '" . $page . "');
                ga('send', 'pageview');


    "));
```

Forms, reports, windows

```
    <!-- additional information -->

    $this->response->insertScript($this->_minify("

                ga('set', 'page', '" . $page . "');
                ga('send', 'pageview');


    "));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your site is a Single Page App so the URL does not change through the user's visit. The is a specific guide for SPA's [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications)

All in all what you want to do is implement 'virtual' pageviews each time a user navigates to a new section of your site. You can set the 'page' attribute on the tracker and send a pageview using the command below

```
ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: The framework keep the same URL while the user navigation. I'll implement this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a third parameter to the pageview call. This works as a virtual URL, i.e. the GA interface show it as a distinct URL in the reports despite the fact that it does not actually exist on the server. If you pass a distinct, meaningful value for every action of the user (or at least any action that changes the content enough to warrant a pageview) then you can tell what they've been up to.

```
 ga('send', 'pageview', '/my/virtual/url/');
```